# How to use "data" or "methods" result to VueRouter prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have simple menu tabs router as follow:

Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3

Routes are attached with individual component to each tab as example below.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/views/type1', component: Type1, props: { listname: value} }
  ]
})
```

Problem:
How route[] prop modify to take the value from "data" of vue. Basically,
one of the component accept property as 'Array' and I need to pull those data from service and attach to component.

```
routes: [
        { path: '/views/type1', component: Type1, props: { collection: *[retrieve from service and attach here]*} }
      ]
```

//collection is not able to bind from "methods" or "data" , it only accepts static data.

Comment: please provide the code of the parent component and a child one

Comment: there is no parent /child .  basically, I want to pass value to routes component props. that value should come from `new Vue({ data or methods}) field. But when I attach "data" property to route then it says, undefined property.

Comment: ok, so provide the main.js code and router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`props`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) field of Vue Router does not hold properties to be passed to the rendered view component, but rather it is a Boolean flag (or a hash/map of view names to Boolean flags) that tells Vue Router to pass any **route parameters** (parsed from the path) as properties to the component.

For example, given the following:

- route config:

  ```
  {
    path: '/user/:name/:uid',
    component: User,
    props: true
  }
  ```
- `User` component definition:

  ```
  export default {
    props: ['name', 'uid']
  }
  ```
- URL:

  ```
  /user/john/123
  ```

Then, `User` would be rendered with `name` set to `john` and `uid` set to `123`, equivalent to this:

```
<User :name="john" :uid="123" />
```

---

If you need to initialize a view with server data, you could wrap the target component (e.g., with `Type1View`) that you initialize after you've fetched the data. In the example below, `Type1.list` is bound to a local `list` data variable. When `Type1View` mounts, we fetch data from the server, and save the result in `list`, which also updates `Type1.list`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Type1 :list="list" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Type1View',
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    const data = await this.fetchData();
    this.list = data.list;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `path: '/user/:name/:uid',`: here, in place of name and uid, need to pass collection from `new Vue({ data: {{ list:[..]});`
  Can we pass collection to component and collection is retrieved on main Vue instance and not into component.

Comment: No, you can't do that through vue-router props. You'd have to route to a wrapper component that sets up `collection`, as I've shown in the answer.

Comment: Ok. so, we can not set collection from vue instance to router props.